# Name of this optimization strategy?

Tags: optimization

Inspired by the approach of this [paper](http://www.simonemanganelli.org/Simone/Research_files/caviarPublished.pdf) and our own experiments, we optimize a complicated function as follows:

```
1. Get an initial estimate
2. Generate M perturbed variants of the inital estimate by adding noise
3. Evaluate the cost of all M starting points
4. Optimize over the N < M best solutions
5. Select the one with the lowest cost as final estimate
```

Is there some "official" name for such an approach? 
The closest I could find is [repeated local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_local_search) but this does not include the `N < M` step.

Comment: Maybe a bootstrap. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)

Comment: @mathreadler I don't really see how this connects to the bootstrap. Could you perhaps elaborate on that?